# what can cause my /dev/video* to get deleted (disabling my camera) and how do I fix it?

Tags: webcam, camera, dmesg

my integrated webcam suddenly stopped working.

Most online advice seem to rely on `v4l2-ctl` which pulls data from `/dev/video0` but apparently this directory does not exist.

Some people seem to have this problem due to camera disabling `Fn+key` combinations but I own a Dell precision 5530 which I don't believe has this Fn option (according to [this](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/sv-se/000128235/precision-5530-keyboard-function-guide?lang=en) at least).

I also tried `dmesg` from which (after some fanangling) I got

```
dmesg | grep -i -e camera -e uvcvideo -e "usb 1-12"

[    2.274981] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.436692] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=6365, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    2.436693] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.436694] usb 1-12: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[    2.436695] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[    3.218112] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:6365)
[    3.218817] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[    3.219327] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
[    3.219329] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[    3.219381] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 1654.404017] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ 1654.655370] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:6365)
[ 1654.656064] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[ 1654.656508] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
[ 1654.656511] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[ 1654.656575] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this "failed to query". Is it just a "it is broken"? could there be another explanation? How would I check? and, if not, would the hardware breaking automatically delete `/dev/video*`? I wouldn't expect that

**Edit:** kernel version `5.4.0-91-generic`

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1881757?comments=all) is exactly the same issue but, if it is, this seems to be a kernel dependent problem so I'll add that my kernel version is `5.4.0-91-generic`

Comment: it "fixed itself" (sorry I can't be more precise :/ ), there was a firmware update in the meantime.